How to make html-to-image work for all divs
I'm using html-to-image to capture screenshots of a div which users can download as a .png file.
This is my code:
export default function App() {
  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  const handleCapture = () => {
    const node = contentRef.current;
    toPng(contentRef.current, { cacheBust: true, height: 410 })
      .then(dataUrl => {
        console.log("Captured image:", dataUrl);
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "lineup.png"
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error capturing screenshot:", error)
      });
  };

const show1 = () => {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div4').style.display = 'none'
  }

  const show2 = () => {
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div4').style.display = 'none'
  }

  const show3 = () => {
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div4').style.display = 'none'
  }

  const show4 = () => {
    document.getElementById('div4').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none'
  }

return (
    <>    
    <div ref={contentRef} className="col-9" id="div1">
        <SoccerLineUp
            size={"fill"} //responsive
            color={"green"}
            pattern={"lines"}
            homeTeam={homeTeam}
            />
    </div>
    <div ref={contentRef} className="col-9" id="div2">
        <SoccerLineUp
          size={"fill"} //responsive
          color={"green"}
          pattern={"lines"}
          homeTeam={formation}
        />
      </div>
      <div ref={contentRef} className="col-9" id="div3">
        <SoccerLineUp
          size={"fill"} //responsive
          color={"green"}
          pattern={"lines"}
          homeTeam={formation2}
        />
      </div>
      <div ref={contentRef} className="col-9" id="div4">
        <SoccerLineUp
          size={"fill"} //responsive
          color={"green"}
          pattern={"lines"}
          homeTeam={formation3}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button className="downloadButton" onClick={handleCapture}>
      Download
    </button>
    <>
   )

However, the download button to capture the .png file is working for the last div with the id of div4. I tried see why this happened and found that whichever div is the last div will have the download button working for it. The download button for all the other divs return a blank black .png file. Are there any modifications I need to make for the download button to work for all divs?

There's only one download button.  How is that function supposed to know which one to grab?

the download button has the onClick event that executes the handleCapture function. The handleCapture function contains contentRef which is referenced in each of the divs. Is the problem with this?

I also added more code that I forgot to add before, show1, show2, show3, and show4 functions which basically hide the other divs and show the div that you selected.

You're using the same contentRef for multiple divs which will not work, contentRef will be the last one only. Show/hide the divs will not do anything to it. Also try to avoid manipulate DOM directly in React, it's anti pattern

I see. What would be a better practice in react to replace manipulating DOM directly?

@ZaidKhan you should use state to control the visibility of the divs instead. You can either make a state for each div individually or simply make one state that take an object that contains all of them then do something like { visibility.div1 && <div> content div 1</div>}
